# Linkedin : [unauthorized]. token expired 2640 seconds ago + Javascript SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am using Linkedin Javascript SDK to login and get access token and it was working fine. As per the Linkedin documentation we need to renew `oauth` token after every 60 days.

From yesterday I am getting following error for some Linkedin account when I am trying to reconnect.

`[unauthorized]. token expired 2640 seconds ago`

But I have recently added the account before 2 hours and now when I reconnect, its throwing the above error.

Yesterday I have visited the https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#
dcoument and they said that the token expiration time is 30 minutes. Adter each 30 minutes I need to renew it.

Does anyone has idea how to renew it from javascript sdk of Linkedin.

Comment: It says what to do in the same section of the docs; maybe read the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: @Deepti how did you manage to access token using JavaScript?  I'm trying to implement, can you please share some sample code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to refresh token:

```
IN.User.refresh()
```